# Create an array by key using two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array... I want my array to be merged by key. Example below

```
       [month] => Array
            (
                [0] => 01
                [1] => 02
            )

        [quantity] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
                [1] => 6
            )
```

I want a array like...

```
array(
[0]=>array(
'month'=>01,
'quantity'=>4
),
[1]=>array(
'month'=>02,
'quantity'=>6
)
```

Comment: Use php foreach and creat new array

Comment: SO is not free code service. Post your attempts what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

use `foreach()` to loop through your array.

```
  $arr["month"][] = 01;
  $arr["month"][] = 02;
  $arr["quantity"][] = 4;
  $arr["quantity"][] = 6;

  foreach($arr['month'] as $key => $val){
      $array["month"][$key] = $val;
      $array["quantity"][$key] = $arr['quantity'][$key];
  }
```

Output will be,

```
Array
(
    [month] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 6
        )
)
```

Comment: This output is same as input, and not same as the expected output, so what's the point?